# Livestream chat example block throwing error. Messagelist = messages.entries is not a function

Tags: javascript, getstream-io

I m attempting to follow the simple live stream tutorial in react.

Using the code from the tutorial as so:

```
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h2>Chat</h2>
      {chatClient && channel.id ?
      <Chat client={chatClient} theme={'livestream'}>
        <Channel channel={channel} Message={MessageLivestream}>
          <Window hideOnThread>
            <ChannelHeader live />
              {!chatIsEmpty ? <MessageList /> : 'Be the first!'}
            <MessageInput Input={MessageInputSmall} focus />
          </Window>
          <Thread fullWidth />
        </Channel>
      </Chat>  : '...Loading'}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

I m using a functional component for the chat:

```
const chatClient = new StreamChat(process.env.REACT_APP_STREAM_LIVE_CHAT_ID);
```

And I initialize as so:

```
  async function initChat () {
    await chatClient.setUser(
      {
        id: 'brendan',
        name: 'Brendan',
      },
      chatClient.devToken('brendan')
    );

    const channelInst = await chatClient.channel('livestream', process.env.REACT_APP_STREAM_CHANNEL_ID, {
      name: process.env.REACT_APP_STREAM_CHANNEL_NAME,
      members: ['brendan']
    });

    setChatIsEmpty(_.isEmpty((await channelInst.watch()).messages))

    setChannel(channelInst)
  }
```

Receiving error:

> TypeError: messages.entries is not a function
>
> MessageList.insertDates
>   src/components/MessageList/MessageList.js:332

[image: Full error image]

If I comment out the `messagelist` component it will render successfully just without the messages obviously and I can send messages through the input.

Comment: What is your node version ?

Comment: node -v
v10.16.3
npm -v
6.14.5

I've actually resolved the issue it was a different third party library script that was failing and for some reason causing stream to fail

Comment: Thanks, I had investigated a bit but couldn't find a reason then thinking for asking more details but resolved, perfect.